# Laravel 5.3, replace pagination links (<< and >>) with images

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5, pagination

How do I replace the custom laravel pagination with images?
I would also like to get the next set of data without reloading the page. 
My controller looks like this.

```
class HomeController extends Controller
{
public function index()
{       
        $featured_products = DB::table('products')
        ->where('feature_type','=',3)
        ->orderBy('created_at','DESC')
        ->simplePaginate(4);


        $latest_products = DB::table('products')
        ->orderBy('created_at','DESC')
        ->simplePaginate(4);


        return View::make('pages.home')
         ->with(['featured_products'=>$featured_products,'latest_products'=>$latest_products]);
}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way would be to just edit the `blade` file for the pagination.

Firstly, in your console run:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-pagination
```

Then go to `resources/views/vendor/pagination/default.blade.php` and you'll see:

```
@if ($paginator->onFirstPage())
    <li class="disabled"><span>&laquo;</span></li>
@else
    <li><a href="{{ $paginator->previousPageUrl() }}" rel="prev">&laquo;</a></li>
@endif

...

@if ($paginator->hasMorePages())
    <li><a href="{{ $paginator->nextPageUrl() }}" rel="next">&raquo;</a></li>
@else
    <li class="disabled"><span>&raquo;</span></li>
@endif
```

You can just replace the `&laquo;` and `&raquo;` with the images you want to use.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/pagination#customizing-the-pagination-view

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

In 5.3 you can [customize pagination views](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/pagination#customizing-the-pagination-view).

In other versions you can try to override this with CSS or you could try to [show links manually](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/pagination#paginator-instance-methods) instead of using `$results->render()` method:

```
$results->count()
$results->currentPage()
$results->firstItem()
$results->hasMorePages()
$results->lastItem()
$results->lastPage() (Not available when using simplePaginate)
$results->nextPageUrl()
$results->perPage()
$results->previousPageUrl()
$results->total() (Not available when using simplePaginate)
$results->url($page)
```